# table is merging with a video when zooming in on Chrome

Tags: css, frontend

I have a table in the left side of the page and a video in the middle.
When I zoom in on Chrome it gets merged and messed up.
I have attached 2 photos so you can see what I mean.

```
table {
text-align: left;
line-height: 40px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 600px;
height: 220px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
border-left: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
border-right: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

I have tried `position: absolute;` doesn't seem to fix it.

[image: 1st photo zoom-in 100% - not messed up]

[image: 2nd photo zoom-in 125% - messed up]

Comment: Please add relevant code as [mcve] so that we can see what is your current implementation.

Comment: @Esko Alright, done

Comment: Can you put codes of player container? you can set width of player container to calc(100% -  600px)

Comment: @Ali Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Ali I've just tested

`table {
 margin: 0px;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: left;
 line-height: 40px;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0;
 width: calc(100% - 600px);
 height: calc(100% - 220px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
 border-radius: 20px;
 }`
and it doesn't change anything

Comment: i answered as a jsfiddle link, hopefully that will help you, I used flex box so both boxes will have 50% width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are million ways to achieve this, one of them is flexbox.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.player, .table-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

table {
text-align: left;
line-height: 40px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0;
max-width: 600px;
height: 220px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
border-left: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
border-right: 1px solid rgba(189, 193, 200, 0.5);
border-radius: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eq0sdvgh/1/